# Modify time:now() to be less one hour

Tags: json, streamsets

First of all, I don't quite know what the core language is of this. I have followed a [tutorial](https://ask.streamsets.com/question/2806/how-to-add-or-subtract-time-from-datetime-field/).

My code looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "dateRange",
    "dateRange": "${time:extractStringFromDateTZ(time:now(), 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS')}/${time:extractStringFromDateTZ(time:now(), 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS')}"
}
```

This gives me the following:

```
{
    "type": "dateRange",
    "dateRange": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000/2019-04-01T00:00:00.000"
}
```

What I am trying to do is take 1h off the first date. This is what I have tried:

Before:

```
${time:extractStringFromDateTZ(time:now(), 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS')}
```

After:

```
${time:millisecondsToDateTime(time:dateTimeToMilliseconds(time:now()) - (3600), 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS')}
```

Although this seems to be valid code, it says its invalid. Please can someone help me understand how to modify the "before" code to be 1 hour from the time now.

Comment: This is not Java.

Comment: Can you please point to the tutorial you are following? It would help to identify a context you seem unable to identify since that is surely not Java.

Comment: @bracco23 https://ask.streamsets.com/question/2806/how-to-add-or-subtract-time-from-datetime-field/ this gives the information its just not in the format I need (UTC)

Comment: What do you mean you *"think it is likely java..."*? How can you try to write code without even knowing what language you are doing it in? I am truly intrigued and baffled in the same time.

Comment: @Matthew It isn't clear what language the tutorial is

Comment: @Jimmy Are you using some sort of compiler to compile your code?

Comment: The "tutorial" looks like a community similar to SO but specific to the platform you are using.

Comment: @Matthew No compiler no

Comment: 3600 or 3600 * 1000 ?

Comment: @vikingsteve - anything really, I dont mind updating the number, I just cant get it to both offset and output in the right format yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS

Comment: What do you use to run this code?

Comment: Using the wrong tags is contraproductive for you, all the Java experts are now seeing this question and the real experts for that topic wont find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as mentioned in the comments to your post, 1h is 3600000 milliseconds

Then, I never worked with `StreamSets` but looking at [the doc](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Expression_Language/Functions.html#concept_qkr_trf_sw):

the signature of the method you try to use is `time:dateTimeToMilliseconds(<Date object>)` and it returns a `Long`
Its description is:

> Converts a Date object to an epoch or UNIX time in milliseconds.

So you can't call it with these parameters `, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS'`

This might be the valid syntax it is expecting:

```
${time:millisecondsToDateTime(time:dateTimeToMilliseconds(time:now()) - (3600000))}
```

You should be using other functions if you want to use a time zone:

`time:millisecondsToDateTime(<long>)` returns a `Date object`
and
`time:extractStringFromDateTZ(<Date object>, <time zone>, <format string>)` returns a String

Can't you chain them like this?

```
${time:extractStringFromDateTZ(
    time:millisecondsToDateTime(time:dateTimeToMilliseconds(time:now()) - 3600000), 
    'UTC', 
    'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS')}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try in this way:

Convert your date in milliseconds then 

`( dateMilliseconds - 3600000)`

The result need to be converted in date.

Comment: I was trying this but it says invalid format ${time:extractDateFromString(time:millisecondsToDateTime(time:dateTimeToMilliseconds(time:now()) - (3600)), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS')}